# How to launch bootstrap modal to launch on same page to save?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

When I click on the button to launch my modal, it rather duplicataes the content on the same browser page and this is the "Js error" i get in my console window. Tried many suggestions but still.Please help.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
at Pe._isAnimated (modal.js:312:26)
at Pe._initializeBackDrop (modal.js:194:24)
at new Pe (modal.js:82:27)
at Pe.getOrCreateInstance (base-component.js:55:41)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:414:22)
at HTMLDocument.n (event-handler.js:120:21)
```

My Code:
Controller:

```
   using BOGBitwiseApp.Data;
   using BOGBitwiseApp.Models;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
   using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
   using System.Dynamic;

   namespace BOGBitwiseApp.Controllers
  {
  public class CustomerRequestController : Controller
  {

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CustomerRequestController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //Get: Customer Requests
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var customerRequest = _context.CustomerRequests.ToList();
        return View(customerRequest);

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        CustomerRequestModel customer = new CustomerRequestModel();
        return PartialView("AddCustomerModelPartial", customer);
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
   @model IEnumerable<BOGBitwiseApp.Models.CustomerRequestModel>
   @{
      ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    }

     <div id="PlaceHolderHere">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs- 
      target="#addCustomerRequest" data-bs-url="@Url.Action("Create")">New Customer 
     Request</button>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AccountName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m =>m.AccountNumber)
        </th>
        <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.AccountName
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.AccountNumber
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.BitwiseId}) ||
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.BitwiseId})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
 </tbody>
```

PartialView:
I created a partialview "AddCustomerModelPartial.cshtml".

```
  @model CustomerRequestModel

    <div class="modal fade" id="addCustomerRequest">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h2 class="modal-title" id="addCustomerRequestLabel">Bitwise 
           Information</h2>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" data-bs- 
                 dismiss="modal">
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                  <form asp-action="Create" >
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="AccountName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="AccountName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="AccountName" class="text-danger"> 
                    </span>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="AccountNumber"></label>
                        <input asp-for="AccountNumber" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="AccountNumber" class="text-danger"> 
                      </span>
                      </div>                      
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs- 
          dismiss="modal">Cancel Request</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save 
          Request</button>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Site.js Code:
This is my js code in the wwwroor folder.

```
$(function () {
  var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');
   $('button[data-bs-toggle="modal"]').click(function (event) {

    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.get(url).done(function (data) {
        PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
        PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
      })
    })
  })
```

Comment: Hi@Rena..I have accepted as answer please. Thanks very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `data-url="@Url.Action("Create")"` if you want to get the value by using `$(this).data('url')`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs- 
  target="#addCustomerRequest" data-url="@Url.Action("Create")">New Customer Request</button>
```

**Another way**, if you **do not want to change** `data-bs-url`, you can change the js below to receive the url value:

```
 var url = $(this).attr("data-bs-url");
```